# Extract numeric part of strings of mixed numbers and characters in R

Tags: string, r

I have a lot of strings, and each of which tends to have the following format: `Ab_Cd-001234.txt`
I want to replace it with `001234`. How can I achieve it in R?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using `gsub` or `sub` you can do this :

```
 gsub('.*-([0-9]+).*','\\1','Ab_Cd-001234.txt')
"001234"
```

you can use `regexpr` with `regmatches`

```
m <- gregexpr('[0-9]+','Ab_Cd-001234.txt')
regmatches('Ab_Cd-001234.txt',m)
"001234"
```

**EDIT** the 2 methods are vectorized and works for a vector of strings.

```
x <- c('Ab_Cd-001234.txt','Ab_Cd-001234.txt')
sub('.*-([0-9]+).*','\\1',x)
"001234" "001234"

 m <- gregexpr('[0-9]+',x)
> regmatches(x,m)
[[1]]
[1] "001234"

[[2]]
[1] "001234"
```

Comment: in your first solution, what does the '\\1' do in gsub?

Comment: \\1 refer to accessing the first matching capture ( what is between parenthesis in the pattern).

Answer (score 41):

The [stringr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) package has lots of handy shortcuts for this kind of work:

```
# input data following @agstudy
data <-  c('Ab_Cd-001234.txt','Ab_Cd-001234.txt')

# load library
library(stringr)

# prepare regular expression
regexp <- "[[:digit:]]+"

# process string
str_extract(data, regexp)

Which gives the desired result:

  [1] "001234" "001234"
```

To explain the regexp a little:

`[[:digit:]]` is any number 0 to 9

`+` means the preceding item (in this case, a digit) will be matched one or more times

This page is also very useful for this kind of string processing: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing

Comment: This method doesn't handle commas correctly

str_extract(c("$555","$6,077"),regexp )
[1] "555" "6"

Comment: where z is your vector - added this first
z <- gsub( "," , "" z ) 
and this worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

You could use `genXtract` from the qdap package.  This takes a left character string and a right character string and extracts the elements between.

```
library(qdap)
genXtract("Ab_Cd-001234.txt", "-", ".txt")
```

Though I much prefer agstudy's answer.

**EDIT** Extending answer to match agstudy's:

```
x <- c('Ab_Cd-001234.txt','Ab_Cd-001234.txt')
genXtract(x, "-", ".txt")

# $`-  :  .txt1`
# [1] "001234"
# 
# $`-  :  .txt2`
# [1] "001234"
```

Comment: +1.  always like learning of new packages.  (eh, "new" to me, as the saying goes)

Answer (score 2):

**gsub**   Remove prefix and suffix:

```
gsub(".*-|\\.txt$", "", x)
```

**tools package**  Use `file_path_sans_ext` from tools to remove extension and then use `sub` to remove prefix:

```
library(tools)
sub(".*-", "", file_path_sans_ext(x))
```

**strapplyc**  Extract the digits after - and before dot.  See [gsubfn home page](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) for more info:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(x, "-(\\d+)\\.", simplify = TRUE)
```

Note that if it were desired to return a numeric we could use `strapply` rather than `strapplyc` like this:

```
strapply(x, "-(\\d+)\\.", as.numeric, simplify = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this answer because it works regardless of what non-numeric characters you have in the strings you want to clean up, and because OP said that the string *tends* to follow the format "Ab_Cd-001234.txt", which I take to mean allows for variation.

Note that this answer takes all numeric characters from the string and keeps them together, so if the string were "4_Ab_Cd_001234.txt", your result would be "4001234".

If you're wanting to point your solution at a column in a dataframe you've got,

```
df$clean_column<-gsub("[^0-9]", "", df$dirty_column)
```

This is very similar to the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52729957/9731173.

Essentially what you are doing with my solution is replacing any non-numeric character with "", while the answer I've linked to replaces any character that is not numeric, - or .