# get the number from character "\n 0.28\n \n " in R language

Tags: r

I would like to get the 0.28 from the character using R
"\n        0.28\n        \n      ".

Maybe I should use sub() function, but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: This is nearly a duplicate of these previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14543627/1036500 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/15451251/1036500 Some of the answers to those questions work here also, eg. `as.numeric(gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", string))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, you want to learn about regular expressions. Which can be intimidating, but you can also learn by example.

Here, we can do something relatively simple:

```
R> txt <- "\n 0.28\n \n "
R> gsub(".* ([0-9.]+).*", "\\1", txt)
[1] "0.28"
R> as.numeric(gsub(".* ([0-9.]+).*", "\\1", txt))
[1] 0.28
R>
```

The `(...)` marks something we "want", here we say we want digits or dots, and several of them (the `+`).  The `"\\1"` then recalls that match.

Alternatively, we could just "erase" all of the `\n` and spaces:

```
R> as.numeric(gsub("[\n ]", "", txt))
[1] 0.28
R>
```

Comment: Great response and well explained example.  Regex needs more of this +1

Answer (score 8):

You don't need regular expressions for your use-case.

```
 string <-  "\n 0.28\n \n "
 as.numeric(string)
 [1] 0.28
```

Comment: Nice one.  Seems to break as soon as there is another digit somewhere but the presented example it does indeed work.

Comment: @Dirk. Wouldn't you want it to break? Using for example `txt <- " \n 1.5 \n 33 \n"` your two solutions would give respectively `33` and `1.533`. Not that your answer was bad.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions so far are great and actually teach you something.  If you want the dumb but simple answer, `taRifx::destring` will work:

```
library(taRifx)
> destring("\n 0.28\n \n ")
[1] 0.28
```

It uses the `[^...]` regular expression idiom ("not") rather than back-referencing as in @Dirk's solution:

```
return(as.numeric(gsub(paste("[^", keep, "]+", sep = ""), "", x)))
```