# Looping and extracting file numbers from .csv file names and inserting into a column

Tags: r, csv

I have managed to combined the data from several files and currently trying to extract a file number from my files and insert these into a column.

````
fnames = dir("../data/temperature_trials", full.names=TRUE)

print(fnames)

for (i in 1: length(fnames) ) {

 #open each file in turn

temp = read.csv(fnames[i])

  if (i == 1) {
    res = temp
  } else {
      res = rbind(res, temp)
    }
}

```
````

Imported 12 .csv files and used rbind to combine all data.Files named:
Trial1.csv
Trial2.csv
.
.
.
Trial12.csv

````
```
   for (i in 1: length(fnames)) {

loc = regexpr(pattern = "Trial[0-9]*", text = fnames[i])

trialNumber = as.numeric(substr(fnames[i], start = loc[[1]][1]+5,
            stop = loc[[1]][1] + attr(loc, 'match.length')-1))
print(trialNumber)

res1 = cbind(trialNumber, res)

```
````

I am trying to extract the trial numbers from each .csv file name and place them into a column named TrialNumber. When I do so it will only place a 12 into this column for every data point. Since it is using a loop I am assuming this is why, but can not figure out how to fix this or another way to do so. I need to assign the trial number to each data point corresponding with each .csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can simply add Trial number during each iteration of the loop-

```
for (i in 1: length(fnames) ) {

#open each file in turn

temp = read.csv(fnames[i])

  if (i == 1) {
    res = temp
  } else {
      res = rbind(res, temp)
    }
res$trial_number=i

}
```

This way you will have a trial number column which will correspond to the file which had been imported.

You can also try extracting the numeric part of the file name as pointed out in this answer-

[Extract numeric part of strings of mixed numbers and characters in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451251/extract-numeric-part-of-strings-of-mixed-numbers-and-characters-in-r)

Comment: This will not work because I have 12 files combined. I need to insert a column with trial number and it should be 1-12 corresponding with the proper .csv file data.

Comment: What I had suggested was that you do this before the end of each iteration, whereas you're currently trying to do it after you've already appended all the files together.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a list of data frames from the CSV files, using the file name as the basis for each list element name:

```
fnames <- list.files("full/path/to/data/temperature_trials", 
                     pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
temp   <- lapply(fnames, read.csv)
names(temp) <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(fnames))
```

Then `dplyr::bind_rows()` will create a dataframe from the list with the treatment label in the `.id` column:

```
library(dplyr)
temp_df <- bind_rows(temp, .id = "TrialNumber")
```