# How can I remove non-numeric characters from strings using gsub in R?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I use the `gsub` function in R to remove unwanted characters in numbers. So I should remove from the strings every character that is not a number, `.`, and `-`. My problem is that the regular expression is not removing some non-numeric characters like `d`, `+`, and `<`.

Below are my regular expression, the `gsub` execution, and its output. How can I change the regular expression in order to achieve the desired output?

**Current output:**

```
gsub(pattern = '[^(-?(\\d*\\.)?\\d+)]', replacement = '', x = c('1.2<', '>4.5', '3+.2', '-1d0', '2aadddab2','1.3h'))
[1] "1.2<"  ">4.5"  "3+.2"  "-1d0"  "2ddd2" "1.3"
```

**Desired output:**

```
[1] "1.2"  "4.5"  "3.2"  "-10"  "22" "1.3"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use `gsub("-", "+", x, fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: Just get rid of the `?`  Use `gsub(pattern = '-', replace='+', x = c('a', 'bc', '-'))`

Comment: It works if you wrap `[]` around what you want to find: `gsub(pattern = '[-?]', replace='+', x = c('a', 'bc', '-'))`

Comment: not a helpful comment @StanislausStadlmann. Should be `gsub(pattern = '[-]', replace='+', x = c('a', 'bc', '-'))`. He does not intend to match a possible `?` character.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, the example I provided is a simplification. In my real problem, I need the `?` quantifier, so I cannot use `fixed = TRUE`.

Comment: You know what to do: update the question with the real life scenario. Then let me know. Right now, I see no point in reopening the post.

Comment: `?` means zero or more instances of the preceding character, so your code adds a + basically *everywhere*, whether there is or isn't a -. Instead, you can use either `-+` (one or more -) or `-` (exactly one minus), like so: `gsub(pattern = '-+', replace='+', x = c('a', 'bc', '-'))`

Comment: @jair.jr please provide a good example in order for us to provide a good solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I updated the question with the real life scenario. Thank you.

Comment: `gsub("[^0-9.-]", "", x)`

Comment: The approach im taking is. Remove everything except `[^THOSE VALUES]`.

Comment: As @AndreElrico points out, a caret as the first character in square brackets means you're selecting for everything *except* what's in the square brackets (rather than its normal meaning as the beginning of a string), so what your code actually does is remove everything except the characters `(-?(\\d*\\.)?\\d+)`

Comment: What if the value is `67-.-<`? How "bad" can those values be formatted?

Comment: Can there be `5g.g6h.h7hh.8`, `9-9.8.9`? There are now too many unclear moments here.

Comment: If Andre's regex works for you please let the user know, so that an answer could be posted.

Comment: Thank you, @AndreElrico. Your suggestion is working for me. I just have to implement an extra step to parse the resulting expression to a number, and discard the value if there's an error during parse. Just for the record, yes there can be `5g.g6h.h7hh.8, 9-9.8.9` or `67-.-<` in the values, but I'm sure the extra parsing step will deal with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Simply use

```
gsub("[^0-9.-]", "", x)
```

You can in case of multiple `-` and `.` have a second regEx dealing with that.
If you struggle with it, open a new question.

---

(Make sure to change `.` with `,` if needed)

Comment: If you have multiple instances of the replacement, you can use `dplyr`'s `str_replace_all`.

Comment: This is actually available via the `stringr` package.